# javascript where clause builder, including functions

Tags: javascript, query-builder

I am looking for a visual javascript `WHERE` clause builder that also supports scalar functions. E.g.,

```
... 
WHERE COL_A = '1234' 
AND IS_HOLIDAY(DATECOL, LOCALITY) 
AND (BASE_MEASURE(UOM, QTY) > 1234 OR AMOUNT > 1234)
...
```

The ones I have seen lack support for functions. (Like in MS-Excel.) They also tend to pull the table schema directly from database which is not suitable for me, esp. as I have just one set to search and have no access to database.

What I have: a list of searchable column names and their data types, several sets of functions (simple mathematical/date/string and many homebrewn ones encapsulating business rules) and their arguments / return types. Null support is not important, nor are function call within function calls. What I need is a javascript library that I can encode for metadata and let loose in a DOM element; it manages the user interactions, returning a WHERE clause string.

I will appreciate if you could please point me to either some good starting code or to an outline on how to add function support, or both.

Thanks.

Comment: I have found this http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/.  you have found a better solution?